# How to fetch and insert image to Mysql using react,fetchApi and nodejs

Tags: mysql, node.js, reactjs, redux, fetch

I want to insert an image to mysql database receiving from < input type='file' / > and after fetching want to display it on < img /> using node and react

Below is my nodejs code .

```
    const {ISBN,publisher,category,edition,image,title,price,quantity,author,}=req.query
console.log(req.query)
    const insertIntoBooks=`INSERT into BOOKS(ISBN,publisher,category,edition,image,title,price,quantity,author) VALUES('${ISBN}','${publisher}','${category}','${edition}','${image}','${title}',${price},${quantity},'${author}')`
connection.execute(insertIntoBooks).then(resp=>res.json({data:'success'})).catch(err=>res.json({data:'error'}))
})
```

above u can see im receiving an image and this image is what i want to save in Mysql.
Below is my react code

```
props.startInsertingBook(`http://localhost:3300/books/add?title=${title}&price=${price}&quantity=${quantity}&author=${authorName}&ISBN=${ISBN}&image=${image}&publisher=${publisher}&edition=${edition}&category=${category}`)
```

Below is my redux Action code.

````
return(dispatch)=>{
    return fetch(`${url}`).then(resp=>resp.json()).then(({data})=>{
        console.log(data);
        if(data==='success'){
          return  toastr.success('Success','Book added Successfuly')
        }else{
return toastr.error('Error','Error in submitting')
        }
    }).catch(err=>toastr.error('oops','error occur due to lost in coonectivity'))

}
}```
````

Comment: i believe the `fetch` code you shared will work on `GET` methods only for `POST` methods `fetch` takes another parameter  of `options`. You can look at the fetch documentation [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch#Supplying_request_options)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As image is in `binary` you can't send it directly through get method.
You need to try `fetch` post method to achieve it.